# Wordpress Loop: Wrap 3 search results in a row

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I have set up my template to output search entries in col-4 to make a 3 column layout, and I need to wrap each set of 3 in a row.

I have come up with the below but it seems my opening and closing PHP is wrong, as I am currently getting each 1 search entry in it's own row. Thanks in advance for help

```
<?php 
if ($counter % 3 == 0) { 
  echo '<div class="row">';
} ?>


<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="search-result col-md-4">
    <?php
    $entry_thumbnail = racks_entry_thumbnail();
    $entry_class = $entry_thumbnail ? 'search-thumbnail' : 'col-sm-4 col-md-4';
    ?>
        <?php if( $entry_thumbnail ) : ?>
            <div class=" <?php echo esc_attr( $entry_class ); ?>">
                <?php echo $entry_thumbnail; ?>

            <header class="entry-header clearfix">
                <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title() ?></a></h2>
                </header>

        <div class="entry-summary">
          <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        </div>

        <footer class="entry-footer">
          <a class="read-more" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php _e( 'Read more', 'racks' ) ?></a>
        </footer>

    </div>
        <?php endif;?>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</article><!-- #post-## -->

<?php $counter++ ; echo '</div>'; ?>
```

Comment: When did you define `$counter`? You didn't show that in your code

Comment: Do you have a loop before this code ? If so, can you show it ?

Comment: The loop is defined before - @rnevius where should counter be defined? In functions.php?? Please excuse me, my php is very limited

Comment: Why have you edited the answer into your question, making it essentially irrelevant to anyone else? If you consider this solution helpful, just accept it; if not, please explain what doesn't work and/or why it's not useful for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't forget you only have to close `</div>` for $counter divisible by 3:

```
<?php 
  echo ($counter % 3 === 0) ? '</div>' : '';
  $counter++;
?>
```

As it stands, you close `</div>` at each step of your loop. Also note that you might want to make this check right at the beginning of the iteration, assign its result into a variable. For example:

```
<?php

$counter = 0;
while ($counter < someLimit):
  $newRow = $counter % 3 === 0;

?>

  // at the beginning of template:
  <?= $newRow ? '<div class="row">' : ''; ?>

  // output goes here

  // at the end of template:
  <?= $newRow ? '</div>' : ''; ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Another approach would be using output buffer to store the output for each element in some array, split this array into chunks (with [array_chunk()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php)), then output those chunks (wrapping each one in `<div class="row"></div>` structure).

Comment: Hey I tried this but now nothing is displaying - there are no rows showing up in the inspector either (I edited my original post to include your code). Thank you for the help

Comment: Is it any error you see there? The original post wasn't complete (no $counter defined, no loop whatsoever etc.), so I've shown only the guidelines in my answer.

Comment: Sorry dude, I explained I am a beginner with php. I have no idea where to define counter. The code I showed is an extra template file placed inside a working loop:

Comment: I'm sorry, but just stitching things together without even basic understanding of their purpose is not a good way of programming. If there's a working loop, why do you add `while` in your template? In this case, you can use the first tip I gave in my answer, ignoring all the part going after 'you might want to'.